# Analytics Question

Tags: discussion

Looking at recent [site analytics](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) (requires 5k reputation, [details](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/)), and last month shows there were three big sites sending most of the traffic here. Not recognizing `hubble.ic.kanazawa-it.ac.jp`, I tried browsing there but keep getting the "Name Not Resolved" error:

```
"This site can’t be reached 

hubble.ic.kanazawa-it.ac.jp’s server DNS address could not be found."
```

Curious if this is a legit URL?
If not, what's going on with GA to make it think it is?

Depending on responses, I'll have more questions.

Comment: in the spirit of OD, should we publish the viewerships stats for all to see?

Comment: anything else would be uncivilized ;)

Answer (score 3):

www.ic.kanagawa-it.ac.jp ([google translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ja&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=www.ic.kanagawa-it.ac.jp&edit-text=)) is the *Kanagawa Institute of Technology - School of Information*, which is a department of a legit academic organization ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanagawa_Institute_of_Technology)).

Maybe *hubble* is a computer running a student web-scraping project?

Perhaps [Nicolas](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/754/nicolas-raoul), who lives in Japan, can reach out to someone in the IC department, to see what is going on.

Comment: interesting. and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the data (2013-May-08 to 2016-Nov-14)

- **[posts.csv](http://pastebin.com/raw/e6WjK2mb)**
- **[traffic.csv](http://pastebin.com/raw/bdPNDF6b)**
- **[votes.csv](http://pastebin.com/raw/azEXhcpY)**

Important dates:

- Private beta:2013-May-08
- Public beta: 2013-May-21

---

And some data visualizations we have access to:

**History**

[image]

---

**Traffic sources**

[image]